# Mixcloud FooterWidget api errors in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox?

Tags: api, footer

I've tried contacting Mixcloud about this but they don't appear to support the FootWidget api as consider it to be experimental. I'm trying to incorporate this into a WP site and have managed to get it working in Firefox but cannot fathom why it's not working in Chrome & Safari. I've checked the console output, Query Monitor and PHP error logs but can't figure out the disconnect.
I get the following errors in Chrome:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.mixcloud.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://mysite.co.uk')

Followed by:

> player-widget_vendor.31ac4e7571f324849be7m.js:19 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at player-widget.5ffe47295603dad997b3m.js:5

Then when I click an item to load into the player I get:

> player-widget_vendor.31ac4e7571f324849be7m.js:18 POST https://www.mixcloud.com/graphql 403

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194409/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-the-target-origin-provided-does

Comment: Thanks, @Himad I did but don't believe that's a similar scenario in that the iframe does load initially, but disappears when any other mixcloud links are clicked.

Comment: Had the same issue. Could solve it by converting the widget into HTML and delete the code with the preview button... May it solve yours too